# Systemctl service dependency without changing service file

Tags: linux, systemctl

I want to make `nginx` service dependent on a service I wrote, say `abc.service`. By dependent, I mean:

- `nginx` service should stop when I stop `abc`
- `nginx` service should start when I start `abc`

A typical way would be to modify `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` and add `Wants abc` directive. However, I don't want to modify `nginx.service` file - as this is shipped with nginx package.

Any other way to do this?

Comment: Create a [drop-in file](https://serverfault.com/questions/824389/varnish-daemon-not-listening-on-configured-port/824399?r=SearchResults#824399).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Never modify a unit delivered in `/lib/systemd/system`, those units are shipped by packages owners, and could be overridden at package upgrade.

**option 1** : create a copy of the unit in `/etc/systemd/system` and modify it. then `systemctl daemon-reload` and you are done. `/etc/systemd/system` is the place for your local units => https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Unit%20File%20Load%20Path

**option 2** : create a drop-in file as suggested by Gerald Schneider.

`root@host# mkdir /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d
root@host# cat /etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/mydeps.conf
[Unit]
Wants=abc.service`

you may also need a directive in abc.service to make nginx stop when abc stops.